# SLD filter questions using the other two conditions

Tags: sld, filter

I would like to specify the color and size in accordance with the speed and scale.
This is a step of respectively 10.

```
    <Rule>
      <Name>rotate_ps1-1</Name>
      <Title>arrow1</Title>
      <Abstract>arrow_rotate_ps</Abstract>
      <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
      <MaxScaleDenominator>5000</MaxScaleDenominator>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>speed</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>0.0</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
            <ogc:PropertyName>speed</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>0.05</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <PointSymbolizer>
        <Geometry>
          <ogc:Function name="startPoint">
            <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Geometry>
        <Graphic>
          <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>ttf://Wingdings 3#139</WellKnownName>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#5F00FF</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </Mark>
          <Size>100</Size>
          <Rotation>
            <ogc:PropertyName>direct</ogc:PropertyName>
          </Rotation>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

The code is a part of my sld code.
When in that way, my sld code is too long.
Is there any other way?

Comment: Why is it too long? I guess you could use between to save a few lines.

Comment: That Code is 1% of the my sld code. (color of 10 step and size of 10 step, 10*10). total code line number is 3000 over

Comment: 3000 isn't too bad,  you weren't going to type them by hand were you?

Comment: But if I add color of 2 step, I will add 600 line at code. I need color of 25 step. I will add 4500 line. then my sld code line is 75000 over. It's so bad..